# restrict google places entry to suggested list in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have google places set to auto fill a form input.   I now need some sort of validation.  I have decided the best way to is to not allow input of any text that is not on the suggested list.  How do I modify the working directive below to do so?  If the text input does not match a valid suggestion I want the text input to clear and model set to ''.

**Angular directive:**

```
.directive('googlelocation', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, model) {
            var options = {
                types: [],
            };
            scope.gPlace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0],
                    options);

            google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed',
                    function () {
                        scope.$apply(function () {
                            model.$setViewValue(element.val());
                        });
                    });
        }
    };
});
```

For reference

**HTML:**

```
 <input class="pb-input" id="plocation" name="plocation" type="text" autocomplete="on" ng-model="formData.PLocation" googlelocation ng-required="true" >
```

**Script ref**

```
 <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `place_changed` listener to this:

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(scope.gPlace, 'place_changed',
                function () {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        var place = scope.gPlace.getPlace();
                        if (!place.geometry) {
                             element.val('');
                        } else {
                             model.$setViewValue(element.val());
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Comment: This is getting closer.  this solution theoretically would work if the user selects something on the list that does not contain geometry (ie. Google's suggestions) which will always be true therefore !place.geometry will never evaluate if Google sends valid results.  What we need is if the user varies from the list by typing in their own text and that does not validate.  Perhaps fire the getPlace event to evaluate the expression if a suggestion was not chosen.